# Questions about registers in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, computer-science, avr

For code like:

```
;; Data definitions go here
.section .data
n1:     .byte 12
n2:     .byte 34
n3:     .byte 21
n4:     .byte 10
result: .space 1

;; Code definition goes here
.section .text
    .global main

main:
    push R17

    ldi R26, lo8(n1)        ; Loading the address of n1 in X
        ldi R27, hi8(n1)

        ld R24, X+              ; Load n1 in R24 and increase address
        ld R17, X+              ; Load n2 in R17 and increase address
        add R24, R17            ; R4 = n1 + n2
        ld R17, X+              ; Load n3 in R17 and increase address
        add R24, R17            ; R4 = n1 + n2 + n3
        ld R17, X+              ; Load n4 in R17 and increase address
        add R24, R17            ; Final result in R24 = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4

        ;; At this point R27:R26 contains the address of result
        st X, R24               ; Store the result

    ;; The result of this function is returned in R25:R24
        clr R25         ; So that R25:R24 has the result in 16 bits.

    pop R17
    ret
.end
```

1) Would the result be the same even if we use R18 instead of R17 and remove popping and pushing R17?

2) Also, just doing clr R25 concatenate R25 to R24? (hence make R25:R24?)

3) Moreover, when performing an operation of instruction like:

ADD R17, R18, is ADD an instruction and R17 & R18 a register? And Where are they stored in AVR architecture?

4) Lastly, why does it save the result in R25:R24, not just returning the value of R24 (that contains n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)?

I am really really new to Assembly language... please enlighten me about it... Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but presumably R18 would have to be saved according to calling convention too
2. That's just zero extending.
3. Yes. They are internal to the cpu but also mapped to SRAM memory address range 0-31.
4. Presumably because the function is expected to return a 16 bit value. Note that it would then be better to perform 16 bit additions too.

Comment: Thank you Jester! does the program always has to return 16 bit value? Also, can you please tell me about the zero extending? Thanks!

Comment: `main` has a return type of `int` so you return whatever size that has. I assume it's 16 bits. Zero extending is just filling the top bits with zero. You can use it with unsigned numbers to convert to a larger datatype.